# wp_insert_post - duration

Tags: posts, mysql, wp-insert-post

i try to import a custom DB to the WP DB with about 2000 rows (custom post type).
the problem is that the insert by `wp_insert_post` takes about a second per insert.

Is this normal ? Is there a fast/alternative solution... I think that a insert query should not take over some milliseconds.

**Edit**

its a remote server and both databases are on it. the queries are in quite normal speed (already tested), just the inserting is the problem.

Need some code ? Ask in comments..

thanks guys.

Comment: You need to add much more info: local/server, how's your custom DB structured, etc. Also: Get the debug plugin (official repo) + extensions.

Answer (score 1):

quite easily.

deactivate Wordpress SEO Plugin by Yoast before you playing around with the `wp_insert_post` function. It delays the function about a factor of hundred.